# How do you split the screen using the Logitech K780 and Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, logitech-keyboard, split-window

With my other keyboard I had the Windows button so I could split the screen whenever I needed but I switched Keyboards to the Logitech K780 and now cannot figure out how to split the screen - there is no Window's button.

Comment: can use use the start button?

Answer (score 0):

It is also known as the "start" key.

[How to Find the Windows Key on the Keyboard](https://www.sleewee.com/how-to-find-the-windows-key-on-the-keyboard/)

> On Logitech keyboards like the Logitech K780 Multi-Device Wireless Keyboard, the Windows key is represented by the `start` key and it’s found between the fn and alt keys.
>
> [image]